# JMeter Getting as Non HTTP response code: java.net.UnknownHostException/Non HTTP response message: in Azure Pipeline

Tags: jmeter, performance, azure-devops, cicd, jenkins-pipeline

There is an requirement to run web based application for Performance Testing in Azure Pipeline.
The Application servers are physical servers.

Recorded the script and run it in virtual machine. It ran successfully without any errors
but Running the same script in Azure pipeline and getting as *Non HTTP response code: java.net.UnknownHostException/Non HTTP response message:url.com.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Also child requests are also showing in the report but we need is parent samplers only to be displayed.

Errors
[image]

Could anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that web sites you're trying to test are not publicly available:

[image]

you can check it yourself using online services like https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/

If you access the website via proxy you can configure the proxy under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request Defaults](https://guides.blazemeter.com/g/the-jmeter-pros-load-testing-checklist/23665):

[image]

If VPN connection is required you need to install VPN client and connect before running the test

With regards to reporting "child requests" you can configure the fields you would like to see via [`jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting), JMeter can generate the value if you click "Export transasctions for report"

[image]